# How to use constants shared by two projects?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a service and an application that communicate with each other: they are in separate packages, and communicate via IPC (in particular through AIDL). The objects that are exchanged during the communication are of `Bundle` type, where each field is associated with a `String` key: therefore, both the service and the application must "share" (ie use) the same keys.

I have therefore thought to define some constants to use the above keys, for example within a class, then use these constants in both service and application. The only alternative I thought of was to create a third project and to define classes with common constants within this third project: after just export this project as a jar file and add it to the other two projects (ie the service and application).

Are there further alternatives?

Comment: If these are both android projects you can have the 3rd project be a library project. Then you don't need to worry about exporting jar files. Just add the library project to each of the other 2 projects.

Comment: @dymmeh: Do you mean a simple java project?

Comment: Nope, he means a library project: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html Library projects are unique in that, they don't need to be compiled to JAR's and added to a parent project. Instead, when you create a library project and tell the parent project to use the library project, it will first compile the library project, then *merge* the code into the parent project at compile time automatically.

Comment: @Gophermofur: Just what I was looking for!